# R: Finding class inheritance structure within an R package

Tags: r, oop, inheritance, package, directed-acyclic-graphs

You can find all the objects in a package with

```
objs <- mget(ls("package:base"), inherits = TRUE)
```

You can select the functions from these with

```
funs <- objs[is.function(objs)]
```

You can get a complete list of the dependencies of the listed functions in a package by applying `codetools::findGlobals()`, `miniCRAN::makeDepGraph`, `pkgnet::CreatePackageReport` (or others) to the function list. All of these functions either graph the resulting dependencies or return an object easily plotable with, e.g., `igraph` or `DependenciesGraph`.

Is there an comparable set of commands to find all the classes created by a package and the inheritance structure of those classes? I know that for most packages the resulting web of class inheritance would be relatively simple, but I think that in a few cases, such as `ggplot2` and the `survey` package, the resulting web of class inheritance could be quite helpful.

I have found a package, `classGraph`, that creates directed acyclic graphs for S4 class structures, but I am more interested in the much more common S3 structures.

This seems brute-force and sloppy, but I suppose if I had a list of all the `class` attributes used by objects in the base packages, and all the `class` attributes of objects in a package, then any of the latter which is not among the former would be new classes created by the package or inherited from another non-base package.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly tricky since I am not aware of any formal definition of a `S3 class`. For R objects the S3 classes are governed by a very simple character vector of class names stored in the `class` attribute. Method dispatch is then done by matching element(s) of that attribute with a function name.

You could essentially do:

```
x <- 1:5
class(x) <- "MyMadeUpClass"
x

# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "MyMadeUpClass"
```

Does the above really define a class in the intuitive formal understanding of the term ?

You can create a `print` method for objects of this class like (silly example incoming):

```
print.MyMadeUpClass <- function(x, ...)  {
  print(sprintf("Pretty vector: %s", paste(x, collapse = ",")))
}
x 
# [1] "Pretty vector: 1,2,3,4,5"
```

The important distinction here is that methods in S3

- "belong to" (generic) functions, not classes
- are chosen based on classes of the arguments provided to the function call

Point I am trying to make is that S3 does not really have a formally defined inheritance (which I assume is what you are looking for), with contrast to `S4` which implements this via the `contains` concept, so I am not really sure what would you like to see as a result.

Very good read on the topic Object-Oriented Programming, Functional
Programming and R by John M. Chambers: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.3531.pdf

Edit (after question edit) - the **sloop** package:

From S3 perspective I think it makes a lot of sense to examine the structure of generics and methods. A found the `sloop` package to be a very useful tool for this: https://github.com/r-lib/sloop.

Comment: I have been under the impression that S3-style classes inheritance is implemented via NextMethod.

Comment: @andrewH, yes, but in context of your question I understood you were interested more in a sort of a "class tree", which makes a lot of sense for S4, but in my view not so much for S3, as the "inheritance" you create with that is object-dependent, not objectclass-dependent, e.g. objects can share a common first class, but have a completely different second class on which the `NextMethod` would be dispatched. What would make more sense in my opinion is to examine this from generic -> method perspective, e.g. with https://github.com/r-lib/sloop